# Why is this (trivial) unit test failing?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, junit, taglib

**This was taken nearly verbatim from IBM's [Mastering Grails](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails03118/) series.**

DateTagLib.groovy:

```
class DateTagLib {
  def thisYear = {
    out << Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)
  }
}
```

DateTagLibTests.groovy:

```
class DateTagLibTests extends TagLibUnitTestCase {
    def dateTagLib

    protected void setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        dateTagLib = new DateTagLib()
    }

    void testThisYear() {
        String expected = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)
        assertEquals("years do NOT match", expected, dateTagLib.thisYear())
    }

    protected void tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }
}
```

`grails test-app DateTagLib` output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
Running 1 unit test...
Running test DateTagLibTests...
                    testThisYear...FAILED
Tests Completed in 359ms ...
-------------------------------------------------------
Tests passed: 0
Tests failed: 1
-------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried matching the types (int/long/String), but I'm still banging my head against the wall.

This test also fails:

```
void testThisYear() {
    long expected = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)
    assertEquals("years do NOT match", expected, (long) dateTagLib.thisYear())
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following instead

```
class DateTagLibTests extends TagLibUnitTestCase {

    void testThisYear() {
        String expected = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)
        tagLib.thisYear()
        assertEquals("years do NOT match", expected, tagLib.out)
    }

}
```

Your original code has 2 problems:

- You should not instantiate `DateTagLib` explicitly. It is already available through a property of the test class named `tagLib`
- `thisYear` does not return the year value, it writes it to `out`. Within a test you can access the content written to the output via `tagLib.out`

Comment: No problem, BTW I don't know whether you're planning to use this taglib or if it's just for illustrative purposes, but it seems fairly pointless to me. IMO, it's almost as easy to use the following GSP code `${new Date()[Calendar.YEAR]}`

Answer (score 0):

`out << Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)` puts the result into `out`, if you want to test this use `def thisYear = { Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) }`